# C# clickclickclick console game - correct button reading

Tags: c#, input, console

I'm trying to create a simple clickclickclick game for the console in c# with Visual Studio. The only thing that is not working yet, is how the console can count presses of *any* button on the keyboard. The problem with the existing code is that the statement stays true even after releasing the button.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
public class clickclickclickgame
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        int amountofpresses = 0;
        timer.Start();
        while (timer.ElapsedMilliseconds < 2000)
        {
            if (Console.KeyAvailable == true) // this is where my question is about.
            {
                timer.Restart();
                amountofpresses++;
            }
        timer.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(amountofpresses);
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to `Read` the key ...

Comment: @Damion Gans Read my answer, I explain some things and have the solution for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace it by:

```
        int i = 0;
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        while(true)
        {
            Console.ReadKey(true);//True makes it so you don't see the key in Console
            if(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < 2000)
            {
                i++;
                sw.Restart();
            }
            else
            {
                sw.Stop();
                break;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Pressed amount: " + i);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

This works like you wan't the only problem is it checks the state after ReadKey witch means if I'm game over I have to press once more for my highscore. btw 2000 ms is 2 seconds, quite high for this game :)
To help you on your way to increasing difficulty id say make 2000 a variable and subtract score * 2 (just an example) every key press. That way it gets harder and harder.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late answer but this does help indeed!! Thanks!